# Django ORM for loop to get queryset

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to use for loop to get list of author with the number of books writing and author with the title of book wrote.
Here is my models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have tried to loop through like this:

```
for a in Author.all():
    books = a.book_set.order_by('author')
    print(books)
```

I get the authors as they are in DB.
Also,

```
for book in book_set.iterator():
...     print(book.title)
```

I got the list of all books.

I use `author_list = Author.objects.order_by("book").count()` which gave the number of author.
How can I loop through the DB and get the Author with number of books, and Authors with book title wrote.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What I want to get is: Authors and book count, and Authors and name of book wrote using for loop. How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you want to list all others with their first 5 books (sorted alphabetically) and their total count of books on one page with a single fetch, you will need to use [aggregations/annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

```
Author.objects.annotate(
    book_count=Count('book'),
    book_list=ArrayAgg('book__title', ordering='book__title')
).order_by('name').all()
```

In your template:

```
{% for author in author_list %}
    {author.name} ({author.book_count}):
    <ul>
    {% for book_title in author.book_list %}
        <li>{book_title}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

This is just a SAMPLE and UNTESTED. It is just to get you started. Please consult the documentation. It makes use of the postgres specific [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg).